# Flag acceptance rate?

Tags: discussion, flag-reviews

What's a normal percentage of declined/disputed flags for reviewers?  1%? 10%? 25%?

I've been trying to help with review queues and I want to make sure I'm not causing more headaches than normal.

Comment: I feel the same way, and hope someone will give guidance on this.  Intuitively, I think about 10% decline/dispute rate is OK, but I have no basis for this.

Comment: FWIW, my figures are *256:helpful, 14:declined, 81,disputed* (total 354 - work out the % values yourself). But to be honest, I'm not sure exactly what *helpful, declined, disputed* actually mean in this context.

Comment: These add up to  351, but that is close enough.  That is a 73% helpful rate, a 4% declined rate and a 23% disputed rate.  What this means, I postulate, is that you don't make many mistakes, but that you are less tolerant of crap than many reviewers.

Comment: FWIW, I'm at 54/2/1 in helpful.declined/disputed, which are roughly 95/3/1%.

Comment: Where are these statistics found?

Comment: @Lawrence On your profile page, make sure Activity is shown ("tab" at the top left) and then click the Helpful flag total in the box on the right.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for the directions - I've found it now. SE keeps comprehensive statistics!

Comment: Another data point: 656/85% helpful, 20/2.6% declined, and 96/12.4% disputed. But that reflects that I don't bother to flag for low-quality or not-an-answer posts since a year or two ago, since so many of them were disputed or declined previously.

Comment: I'm at 162/2/2, which is roughly 98%/1%/1%.